# UIpath - Can't obtain text value inside multiple input fields

Tags: rpa, uipath

I have a situation where I need to obtain the text inside many input fields on an IE-only web page. I can get the text all in one but to filter that would be troubling and I thought maybe if I see if anyone knows how to use the right selector. My idea was to pinpoint using the get text selector but reference the right fields. The problem is it seems the get anchor is the only way to return the text in the input field below the label. This is fine but how can I use multiple anchor selectors in the one get text activity? or should I make it all separate get text activities?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the computerVisionPack. You can find it in the official uipath packs in the uipath studio package manager, and you can find documentations for it here: https://academy.uipath.com/learn/course/639/ai-computer-vision-20

if this is not working for you, please post the site that you need to obtain the text